# Trim Trailing Whitespace from ALL files in workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3

I know about the Trim Trailing Whitespace command in the pallette, and I know I can run this on save.

Is there a way to trim trailing whitespace on ALL files in a workspace (either with some command combo, or a way to run "save" on every file)

I have seen other answers on how to trim trailing whitespaces using Unix tools, but I would rather use the built in tool from VSCode specifically. (I would accept an answer that shows how to do this in another GUI text editor like Sublime Text also).

I would prefer not to have answers that use Terminal or other Regex matching--I would prefer to use the exact algorithm that is used by GUI tools already, since I trust that they will do the thing I expect. I will be running this on potentially thousands of files, so mistakes could easily go through even after audit.

I am basically trying not to open every file and ⌘+S it manually.

I am on macOS if that changes anything (but I doubt it matters)

Comment: In the case of Sublime, it's trivial to run the command on all open files without saving them first; however the API doesn't provide a list of files in the project, so a plugin solution would have to scan all of the project folders themselves.

Comment: @OdatNurd how do I do this trivial thing in Sublime?

Comment: For occasional one-off use, open the Sublime console with `View > Show Console` or the associated key and then run the following code: `[view.run_command("trim_trailing_white_space") for view in window.views()]` . If you want to do it often, define a `WindowCommand` command and put it in there, then bind the command to a key or add it to the menu. You need to swap `window` for `self.window` in that case.

Comment: That's a good start. I will have to dive deep into the API to figure out how to get a list of all the files.

Comment: Of particular interest is something like `window.project_data()["folders"]` which will give you the list of folders in the current project (this can be `None` if no folders are open). From there `os.walk()` can give you contents. You need to honor any exclusion patterns from the project settings yourself, though (possibly using `fnmatch.fnmatch()`).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the search-and-replace function (keyboard shortcuts given below are for Linux, likely similar to what exists on a Mac):

1. Ctrl-Shift-H (open the search-and-replace side panel)
2. Type  `+$` in the Search field (that is a space, a plus and a dollar, meaning one or more spaces anchored at the end of the line)
3. Click the `.*` regular expression button next to the Search field
4. Leave the Replace field empty
5. Press Ctrl-Alt-Enter (or press the Replace All button next to the Replace field)
6. Click Replace (or Alt-R) in the confirmation pop up which also tells you the number of occurrences and files that will be touched

Be careful, as a wrong search or replace argument can mess up many files all at once!